# What is the difference between views and temporary tables in mysql? which is better?

Tags: mysql, view, cart, temp-tables

What is the difference between views and temporary tables in mysql? which is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance between Views and Temporary table is straight forward.

They depend on their definitions :

**Temporary tables are just the tables in tempdb.
Views are stored queries for existing data in existing tables.**

Temporary table needs to be populated first with data, and population is the main preformance-concerned issue.

So the data in views already exists and so views are faster than temporary table.

If any issue or query please let me know.

Comment: _"So the data in views already exists and so views are faster than temporary table"_ Aren't views just aliases for select statements? And as such, won't they be executed each time they are accessed?